# Why does C have a `hypot` function?

Tags: c, optimization

It is clearly possible to compute `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` without using the `hypot(x,y)` function. Why is this function part of the standard?

Is this related to some internal (hardware based) optimizations?

Comment: All the functions in the `math.h` library can be programmed "by hand" with more or less difficulty, that is not a reason for it to not be part of the standard. `sqrt` can also be computed https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905298/6865932.

Comment: Good discussion [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot), with implementation technique and some references.

Comment: In additional to avoiding undue overflows or underflows, `hypot(x,y)` may produce a more accurate result than doing it manually, alhough that's a quality of implemenation detail rather than part of the standard. For example, the IEEE-754 version of `hypot` in GNU Glibc claims the error in the return value is less than 1 ulps (units in the last place).

Comment: @rici Thanks for the link, yet ["Finally, the multiplication by |x| cannot underflow"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot) fails in the corner case of `x,y` both subnormal and the product is inexact. the result can [underflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42277132/2410359).

Comment: @chux: AIUI, `|x|` is multiplied by the square root of a number between 1 and 2 (regardless of how that number was computed). That square root must therefore be between 1 and sqrt(2), and is not a subnormal. It's possible that |x| is subnormal, but how can multiplying a subnormal by a number between 1 and sqrt(2) underflow? The result is as precise as the subnormal was. Perhaps I don't understand the precise meaning of underflow. In any case, I doubt the wikipedians involved in that page are reading this thread, and I'm not one of them. Perhaps you should try the talk page.

Comment: @rici 1) "how "can multiplying a subnormal by a number between 1 and sqrt(2) underflow?  --> If the product is a subnormal and imprecise - in this case, `x` and `y` would both be subnormals.  2) I'll look into a wiki edit.

Comment: @chux: `y/x` is indeed problematic if both are subnormals, I agree. But the square root is still going to result in a number between 1 and sqrt(2). And the sentence you are talking about is about "the multiplication by `|x|`", which I take to mean to specifically be the multiplication of `|x|` by the square root, and not the computation of the square root (which has already happened at that point). So, `|x|` might be a subnormal. If it is, both are, becuase `|x|>=|y|`. The multiplication is `|x|` by a normal between 1 and 1.41 (approx.). Can that underflow? How?

Comment: @chux: I only ask out of curiosity :-) I take no responsibility for the WP page, but I read it and it all seemed reasonable enough. Not that I'm a specialist in the area, or anything. (I also think that there are no problems if you happen to have 80-bit long doubles on your hardware, but I could be wrong about that, too.)

Comment: @rici  "Can that underflow? How?" --> if the product is an imprecise subnormal.  "underflow" does not mean the product is zero, just less than the smallest _normal_ value and imprecise.  Since `x` is a  subnormal in this case, the product can also be-subnormal, even if it is larger than `x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `hypot` function performs this calculation while avoiding overflows.

Section 7.12.7.3p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `hypot` function states:

> The `hypot` functions  compute  the  square  root  of  the  sum  of
> the  squares  of `x` and `y`, without undue overflow or underflow.  A
> range error may occur.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, [all glibc does](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/92b9636/sysdeps/i386/fpu/e_hypot.S#L48_) is `sqrt(x*x + y*Y)`.

Comment: Having a `double` overflow is quite hard isn't ? Does it mean this function is slower than doing the `sqrt` directly?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `hypot(x,y)` avoiding undo overflow ([@bush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63342250/2410359)) and potentially providing a more accurate answer ([@Ian Abbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342198/why-does-c-have-a-hypot-function/63342555#comment112006371_63342198)) than `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`, a subtle corner case is defined.

If std library adheres to ANSI/IEEE 754,  `__STDC_IEC_559__` defined, then

> hypot(±∞; y) returns +∞, even if y is a NaN.  C17dr § F.10.4.3

`sqrt(x*x + y*y)` would not.

---

There might be a cost: [Why hypot() function is so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3764978/2410359).  It is a quality of implementation concern.

> Is this related to some internal (hardware based) optimizations?

[@njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58529704/2410359) discusses this.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` doesn't have to be equal to the value of the `hypot(x, y)`. Example for demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

int main (void)
{
    double x = DBL_MAX/2, y = x;
    printf("x = %g, y = %g\n", x, y);
    printf("sqrt(x*x + y*y) = %g\n", sqrt(x * x + y * y));
    printf("hypot(x*x + y*y) = %g\n", hypot(x, y));
}
```

The `hypot(x,y)` gives the (approximately) correct result even if the arithmetical value of `x*x + y*y` is greater than `DBL_MAX`.

Comment: Note that the compiler, compilation options, and the execution environment can affect the result of this code. One possible difference is if `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` is computed per the semantics of the abstract machine or if extended precision is allowable for intermediate results. In the first case, `x*x` can overflow, but might not if extended precision is used.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath for some possibilities.